# If I were to make a species that had semi plant like functions but was designed to be a hunter what traits would clash against each other

Tags: xenobiology

I named the species Smiles due to the constant grin they have on their faces. Their body is a perfect circle and they have 4 long limbs made of tendons and cellulose. The idea is if you cut off their limbs the cellulose would grow outward from the cut area and stem cells would grow off of the cellulose like scaffolding. Also after 50~ years of being alive, they bury themselves in the ground and spread their limbs outward until they die. But their body grows into a tree that leads to the second, longer phase of their life. They turn into a giant tree-like organism that sits in place and survives off of the food reserves they made in their previous life creating more Smiles, kinda like a coconut tree making coconuts generally 100,000 of these Smiling fruits will be made. Also, they are about as smart as a dog. They hunt in packs and share food. They're fast and strong but most of their organs have been simplified into this conglomerate of organs and muscle that's like an all-purpose organ. They sense via vibrations, temperature, and touch. They have no eyes and their skin is incredibly tough, being able to handle weapons fire up to explosives. Their speed is very fast outmatching cheetahs, however, if they open their teeth they leave their organ(s?) open to attack. Their teeth are a bit more durable than the rest of their body, being able to handle explosive attacks. And are surprisingly sharp, chomping through tank armor. They typically rush down prey with 1-3 smiles going directly towards the target and 2 going for the right and another 2 going for the left of the target. I don't know much about anatomy but I'm unsure how cellulose might affect how they hunt as well as their strange reproduction cycle.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In your current form the answer would be "everything". Also some things are unclear, like "tough" means the ability to survive damage while resistance means ability to prevent damage, yet you say "tough enough to handle explosives" without even specifying what kind of explosive. A grenade, a stick of dynamite, a nuclear bomb? Something strong, fast, tough, cellulose constructed (no skeleton?) And with a simplified mass organ system has everything clash with everything else. You can combine some in a complex organism (Elephant does resistant, speed and strength by pure bulk) but as described...

Comment: Hi Leaf. It'd be worthwhile taking the [tour] and referring to the [help] for guidance to get the hang of the way to approach questions so they're likely to get the kind of useful answers you're looking for..

Comment: "They turn into a giant tree-like organism that ... survives off of the food reserves they made in their previous life" - the energy/nutrients balance does not work out here. Where is the biomass to build "a giant tree-like organism" coming from? Or they are making food stashes like squirrels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to say from an evolutionary and biological perspective this is not a very realistic creature.  Now if your going for soft sci-fi you may be able to get away with stuff like this, god knows Star Trek was practically designed to make physicists cry and it's managed to do well enough to spawn more generations then I can count right now.  If you really want something like this it's going to be impossible to really justify so you may just want to just accept your writing soft sci-fi, declare [rule of cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool), and just do your own thing biology be damned.  However, since you did ask what didn't work I'll try to touch on a few of the more major issues (because frankly touching on all of them is too daunting a task for me...)

**Why thermodynamics hate superbeings**

The old adage that you don't get anything for free applies significantly here.  You created a species that has massive advantages like impervious skin, ability to cut through everything, super strong, fast, able to spawn children at an alarming rate etc etc.  But you don't get all that for free.

For example to bite through a tank you would need an absurdly strong biting strength.  That costs energy to grow and support the muscles and other tools require to give one that strength.  It costs so much energy that you would be dedicating a decent amount of the energy you take in from the food you eat every day to supporting all that muscle growth.  Why would a creature spend that much energy to be able to eat through a tank?  Is it regularly eating tanks?  If not evolution would go out of it's way to make the bite strength weaker to save on energy, because why pay for stuff you never (or very rarely) use?

I could go on with all the other things I listed, but it would take too long to touch on each individually.  The short version is that they all cost too much investment to support and provide too little return for that investment.    A creature that strong would likely starve to death because it was wasting too much resources in building up impervious skin.  It's simply not realistic.  Creatures evolve to be just strong enough to face and (usually) defeat threats in front of them and not much more then that.  That's so they can save energy and put it towards their real goal of making babies.

Unless your creatures are regularly dependent on biting through tanks and surviving explosions to survive they should not be able to do any of that stuff.  Even if they are the energy investment for it all is so high it would take quite a bit of work to explain how they are taking in enough energy to justify all this.  That's before you get into the issues or how it was even possible to have things such as impervious skin that still if flexible and didn't impede growth.

**Speed or resistance, pick one**

You can't have fast and impervious creatures.  It is possible to be somewhat impervious ('survive explosions' is a pretty high bar for any living creature mind you...) but this is usually done by building up extremely tough, thick, skin that is neither flexible nor light.  This weighs you down and gets in the way of fast movement.

Evolution is going to need to pick one, resistance to physical damage or mobility.  You just don't get both at once.

**Death by overpopulation in just one generations**

Your 'birth' rate is insanely high.  Generally a species is going to have just enough children reach adulthood as they have adults pass away each generation so their overall population size stays roughly the same.  There may be a bit of fluctuation but even with the most invasive of species it's not expected that the difference will be that large.  Ultimately a species population can only grow as fast as it's food source is able to provide it energy, producing more children then that will just force your kids to waste energy fighting each other for limited food, eventually consuming all the prey and then starving your children to death once their prey was all eaten.  It's just not a sustainable solution.

So You're trees make 100,000 children in a lifetime of one tree.  That means you are expecting roughly 99,999 children to die in that same lifetime.  What is killing all of them?  Actually the answer to that is obvious, starvation because there is no prey species that can hope to reproduce fast enough to be able to feed such a huge population.

I could go on and on, but suffice to say you need to drastically cut down on your children.  apex predators like this intentionally birth small number of children explicitly so they can keep their numbers low enough that they won't run out of prey.

**Tree's aren't efficient for birthing animals**

Plants gain energy via photosynthesis, and such 'free' energy sure is convenient.  Unfortunately it comes in limited supply.  The rate that plants take in energy is tiny compared to the rate that moving animals consume it.  That's why trees take decades to grow, that's the fastest they can grow because the energy and resources they are taking in is coming in at such a slow rate.

That means the energy produced by photosynthesis is way too low to 'feed' the growth of an animal, who's body and build will be designed, by necessity, so that even when mostly passive, such as while it's growing, it's consuming significantly more energy then plants produce.

Now you did say that your trees are going to use stockpiled resources so maybe you could argue the tree isn't depending on photosynthesis and is just converting it's stockpiles of food into creatures and happens to be in tree shape.

Problem is, why stockpile the energy for so long like this?  If you stockpile energy you need to protect your stockpile.  If that stockpile is stored in your own body then you would have to be *massive* to fit it all, so big that you're not a super fast apex predator any more.  If you store it in some food cache then you need to keep it from spoiling and spend a significant amount of time and energy preventing other creatures from stealing it.  Worse the moment you turn into a tree you have no means of moving to protect your stockpile and thus it will all be stolen.

Put simply stockpiling energy for so long is inefficient and prone to others trying to take it.  It's better to use that energy, by popping out babies as quickly as you can save up enough energy for a single child, then to try to stockpile it for your entire life.  This also has the added advantage of spreading the birth of your children out which helps with overpopulation issues mentioned before.  Plus if you are having kids as quick as you can afford them then if you die prematurely without turning into a tree at least you have had some kids before your death, instead of the all or nothing approach of tree hood where you could spend a lifetime saving up resources only to die of a cold a week before turning into a tree and wasting all that effort.

**It's hard to be smart with no one to teach you**

Creatures that rely solely on instinct don't learn complex social behaviors required for pack life.  To be as smart as a dog, which is pretty smart by most animal standards, you need to be *taught*.  That means you need an older generation that already knows things to teach you how to survive, how to hunt, how to handle complex social pack behaviors.  You need a teacher!

But if your tree is already effectively dead, it's not moving, talking, or teaching, then who is around to teach your children?  At best you could argue younger siblings of the tree adopt it's kids to teach them, but putting all that parental investment on someone that has, at best, half as much genetic investment in the child as a parent is already a bit difficult to see being a stable evolutionary niche.  And of course you would need some way of distributing your children to siblings, what happens when your sibs fight over who will take the next child since none want to take on the burden and wish to make someone else take it on?  this also traces back to the issue with over population as well as you really need to solve the question of population size and how to keep the species from killing all it's prey first to even understand social dynamics enough to dream of a way to assign teachers to children.

**Smart people enjoy sex!**

Okay I admit this probably shouldn't be on the list of 'big' problems since only geeks/nerds obsessed with evolution like me would notice it, but it bugs me so I'm mentioning it.  You make it sound like your trees are producing kids without sex.  The problem is sex is super useful from an evolutionary perspective.  Recombining of genes is a great way to discover new combinations that work better then existing ones.  More important it ensures when a beneficial mutations occurs it can properly spread through the population.  While this is such a horrible oversimplification i'm almost loath to say it put short things 'evolve' faster with sex.

Complex, sapient, pack creatures are quite improbably to be produced without sexual reproduction, the evolutionary drive is just not the same without recombination of genes.  In fact *pack* behavior definitely doesn't happen without sex, because packs almost always start out built around families that have meaning precisely due to sexual reproduction.  Pack behavior just doesn't evolve without sex or some equivalent means to recombine DNA.

**Organs aren't just there for pretty**

We have specialized organs because we *need* them to survive.  You can't just 'simplify' those organs any more then you could simplify the engine, brakes, and suspension in a car into one thing.  They are specialized to do their job the best and one organ trying to do all those things at once is going to suck at all of them.  Specialization is more efficient at getting jobs done that *need* to be done. You can't just simplify and get rid of necessary things required to live.

Okay I said I'd only hit on the big ones, and so I'll leave it there and not waste time on the many other potential issues.  The short version is there is no chance this species could realistically exist and I can't think of a viable way to make it realistic without completely altering it to the point of not looking anything like your species.

My advice is if you want something like this just accept you are writing soft sci fi and run with it.  You're throwing the rules of science out the window and asking your audience to go in knowing that, and there are those that can enjoy stories like that (not me personally, but plenty can).  But at that point there is no reason to ask us what makes sense, you've already thrown out science so just have fun with it at that point.